# 'cmake' will raise "OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake" error (when configure OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, cmake-gui

Recently I am tring to build OpenCV4 use `cmake` and vs2019 in Windows, but when I configure something, I got the following ERROR:

*CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 (message):

CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install
  directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1059 (include)*

I check the file OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 and find these:

```
if(IS_ABSOLUTE "${__python_path}")
    set(OPENCV_PYTHON_DIR_RELATIVE_CMAKECONFIG "${__python_path}")
    message(WARNING "CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install directory")
```

But my "python_path" is right, and I have no idea. Do you know what should I to do ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The compilation was still successful after ignoring this warning. So the second time I built it, I removed the configuration option(OPENCV_GENERATE_SETUPVARS).